# Assigning Wordpress query result to js variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am extremely new to WordPress customisation world and I am working on a task, where I am supposed to assign the content of specific page of WordPress to the JS variable, I am able to fetch the content of the page i need and I can also see in the chrome console tab the content of the page being assigned to the variable, however i am stuck at the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Here is the code I wrote, I am not sure if this is the right way to do things in WordPress but it does seem to give me the result I need so any correction on this approach is also welcome

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var intern = '<?php
                    $internPageId = jobboard_option('intern_tab_page');
                    $the_query = new WP_Query('page_id='.$internPageId);
                    while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        the_content();
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata()?>';
        var company = '<?php
                    $companyPageId = jobboard_option('company_tab_page');
                    $the_query = new WP_Query('page_id='.$companyPageId);
                    while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        the_content();
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata()
                ?>';
        $('#intern-content').click(function () {
            console.log(intern);
            $('div.tabs-content').html(intern);
        });
        $('#company-content').click(function () {
            $('div.tabs-content').html(company);
            console.log(company);
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see the code does seem to pull the text of the page but with an error.

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: for some reason the image is not uploading

Comment: `'`Quote is missing ..

Comment: You're missing the quotes.

Comment: What does your console tell you? Any error showing?

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'`

Comment: @NijrajGelani yes tried that as well

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the console log says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: @Saadia you mean `"` on the outside and `'` in the inside?

Comment: @NijrajGelani I mean if i replace the single quote ' with double quote " that does not work either

Comment: @Saadia can you copy paste the script generated after putting quotes into the question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check this out

```
<?php
$internPageId = jobboard_option('intern_tab_page');
$post_me = get_post($internPageId); 
$excerpt = $post_me->post_content;

$companyPageId = jobboard_option('company_tab_page');
$post_me2 = get_post($companyPageId); 
$excerpt2 = $post_me2->post_content;
?>

<input type="hidden" id="intern_tab_page" value="<?php echo $excerpt;?>">
<input type="hidden" id="company_tab_page" value="<?php echo $excerpt2;?>">

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var intern = $('#intern_tab_page').val();
        var company = $('#company_tab_page').val();
        $('#intern-content').click(function () {
            console.log(intern);
            $('div.tabs-content').html(intern);
        });
        $('#company-content').click(function () {
            $('div.tabs-content').html(company);
            console.log(company);
        });
    });
</script>
```